# class cast exception while converting string to date class object?

Tags: date, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert string into date type object but keep getting class cast exception.I checked everywhere and found the same way as I am using .I have no idea what mistake I am committing.kindly help.

```
String str;
SimpleDateFormat formatter;
Date date;


str="12/23/2011"
    formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    try {
    date=(Date)formatter.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine with me, maybe you made an error with the imports.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "12/23/2011";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date date = null;

        try {
            date = formatter.parse(str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```